# RxDB RxDatabaseBase DexieError

Tags: typescript, persistence, dexie, rxdb

I am trying to implement [signalDb](https://signaldb.js.org/getting-started/)  with [RxDB](https://rxdb.info/quickstart.html)

Just following this [example](https://signaldb.js.org/todo-example/) by signalDb
(Here's the source code of this [example](https://github.com/maxnowack/signaldb/blob/main/example/src/containers/App/index.tsx))

Ang I got this error:

```
DexieError {_e: Error
    at getErrorWithStack (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=85ffa25002a8a31ff006…, name: 'PrematureCommitError', message: 'Transaction committed too early. See link here', inner: null, _promise: DexiePromise, …}
```

Here's the code:

persistence.ts

```
const createDatabase = async (dbName) => {
  const dbPromise = createRxDatabase({
    name: dbName,
    storage: getRxStorageDexie(),
  });
  await dbPromise.then(async (db) => {
    const res = await db.waitForLeadership();
    await db.addCollections({
          todo: {
            schema: todoSchema,
          },
        });
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me to understand or resolve this issue. Thank you in advance